# form.show modeless from ribbonbar

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

I have an addin that shows a tool window as showdialog from a button on a ribbonbar. This model version works fine.  Now I need to allow interaction with the spreadsheet 'under' the form.  I have tried:

```
spec.Show(((IWin32Window)Globals.myAddin.Application.ActiveWindow));
```

And I get a "suspicious cast" error. Of course 'this' fails miserably as the toolbar is not a form castable to 'IWin32Window'

I would like this to function like the built in find window where you can call it up and still interact with the underlying spreadsheet.  The form is very plain:

```
public partial class Spec : Form
```

Clearly, I am missing something. TIA

---

Adding this based on Slaks comment:

```
    public class DialogService
    {
        public void ShowDialog(Form dialog)
        {
            NativeWindow mainWindow = new NativeWindow();
            //mainWindow.AssignHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
            Application app = new Application();
            mainWindow.AssignHandle(new IntPtr(app.Hwnd));
            dialog.Show(mainWindow);
            mainWindow.ReleaseHandle();

        }
   }
```

Issues when using app.Hwnd or Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle the form dissapears immediately.  Perhaps i have overcomplicated this. Is there a better way to go than what I have done here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own class that implements `IWin32Window` and returns Excel's `HWND` from its `Handle` property.